# Can't figure out, how to change select box color, when option selected

Tags: javascript, colors, background

I have HTML like this one:

```
<select onclick="colorchanger()">
  <option name="white" value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option name="red" value="1">Work</option>
  <option name="green" value="2">Doesn't Work</option>
</select>
```

I need to change select box color, when option is selected. I understand how to change color by using value, but i need to use name.
Can anyone help? How to write javascript for this function?

Comment: Why you want to use name ?

Comment: it is not possible generally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
function colorchanger(op){
  var color = op.options[op.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
  op.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
```

```html
<select onclick="colorchanger(this)">
  <option name="white" value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option name="red" value="1">Work</option>
  <option name="green" value="2">Doesn't Work</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'onchange' handler.  Shouldn't be necessary to change the color every click.

```js
function colorChanger(select) {
  var color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('name');
  select.style.backgroundColor=color;
};
```

```html
<select onchange="colorChanger(this);">
  <option name="white" value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option name="red" value="1">Work</option>
  <option name="green" value="2">Doesn't Work</option>
</select>
```